# Encrypt a file in node and decrypt in java using "AES/GCM/NoPadding". Basically AES/GCM/NoPadding equivalent in node.js

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I have encrypt the file using node.js and decrypt in JAVA. Decryption is done in JAVA using "AES/GCM/Nopadding" algorithm and it is third party app hence I cannot change the JAVA code.
I am encrypting the file in node.js using "aes-256-gcm" (not sure if it is equivalent to "AES/GCM/Nopadding") algorithm.

I have tried with crypto, node-forge npm module also tried setting cipher.setAutoPadding(false). But no luck.
Could you please guide me where I am going wrong.

code in node.js

```
const
 algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm',
 randomKey = crypto.randomBytes( 32 ),
 randomIv = crypto.randomBytes( 16 );
const
 cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( algorithm, randomKey, randomIv ),
 input = fs.createReadStream( './imageTest.jpg.gz' ), //gzip image 
 output = fs.createWriteStream( './imageTest.jpg.gz.enc' );

input.pipe( cipher ).pipe( output );
```

code to decrypt in JAVA

```
byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrptedData, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {

    GCMParameterSpec ivSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), ivSpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
}
```

When decrypting the file I get the below error at `cipher.doFinal(encryptedData)` step

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:571)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1046)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:983)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
```

so I need to know how to achieve an equivalent in node.js

Comment: You need to be in contoll of the tag ... [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321549/tag-mismatch-error-in-aes-256-gcm-decryption-using-java?answertab=votes#tab-top]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line into NodeJs after the decryption is finished to get the authentication tag.

```
const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
```

Transmit this tag, too.

And. in Java part, append it before `dofinal`

```
cipher.update(textBytes);
```

Comment: Then send the authenticated tag appended to the ciphertext?

Comment: you mean concat tag with cipher key or encrypted data ? could you please provide more information on this ?

Comment: With the encrypted data. The last part of the ciphertext must be the authentication tag.